# How to get message tracking logs from Office 365? Any APIs?

Tags: office365

How can I get message tracking logs from Office 365? Will Graph API or PowerShell work? Is there any other solution, like auto forwarding or any other option?

Comment: Maybe edit, reword and expand your question, as it is rather terse.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to track messages in Office 365 – PowerShell and EAC.

You can use PowerShell to search through message tracking logs on on-premises servers as well as to trace messages in Exchange Online. 
And although the experience is somehow similar, there are some differences worth mentioning.

On-prem Exchange did not allow message tracking via Exchange Admin Center. In Office 365, EAC enables message tracing and offers quite a comfortable experience.

Please see this link:
[Message tracking in Office 365 (Exchange Online)](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/message-tracking-office-365/)